# Creating a Custom Cursor in Console-based C++ Program

Tags: c++, cursor

By cursor, I mean a sign (I was thinking '>') that would appear when I ask the user to make a choice between pre-defined options and would allow them to press Up, Down and Enter to select their option.

I'm currently giving the user option of either '1' or '2' and they have to manually enter their option. Whilst this is working just fine, I was wondering if there was a way to do the afore mentioned, as it would probably save me time on error checking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In standard C++, there is no concept of "cursor" in the console.  Any more features requires platform specific features.  You forgot to mention the platform you are working with.

Comment: You may want to consider shifting your design to GUI based.  A GUI based program will have more options, such as drop-down selection lists and checkboxes for menu selections.

Comment: Write a function that prints out whatever message the caller wants printed and then prints a '>'.

Comment: You could take a look at [ncurses example using C++](https://gist.github.com/daleobrien/7535489).

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Thanks for the reply! I'm currently working on Windows 7, and I'm not really keen on switching to a GUI as I have no experience with it.